# Difference route / path?

Tags: meaning

Is there a difference between the meaning of the words "route" and "path" or can these words be used interchangeably?

Comment: In general, it is not possible for two words to be used interchangeably in every context. _Path_ can mean a footpath, contrasting with a paved sidewalk, for instance, and _route_ can refer to a superhighway. Metaphorically, they're the same; but then there aren't really any paths or routes when dealing with thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a non-native speaker. Thus, take the following information with a grain of salt.

A route always has a specified beginning and destination and can be imaginary (e.g proposed by a malfunctioning navigation system). A route can be part of a path when only a section of the path is actually traveled.

A path is always physical available and may end in a rather unclear manner (e.g A footpath in a forest that blurs away). One or more paths can be part of a route.

`Path` is also used to describe a way in which a person or thing is moving as well as a way leading to a desired achievement.

Answer (score 1):

'Path' is more a wandering, unclear way, and 'route' is always definite.